# convert calendar weeks into daily dates

Tags: r, calendar, time-series

I got a list with two columns, calendar weeks for 2015 and a value:

```
calender week   Value
        KW 1    14000
        KW 2    24000
```

There is - unfortunately - no more information in the file I received. What I need for analysis, though, is a daily time series, hence I need to convert KW 1 etc into a column with the respective dates (Note: the calendar week always starts with Monday!):

```
calender week   date        Value
      KW 1      29-12-13    2000
      KW 1      30-12-13    2000
      KW 1      31-12-13    2000
      KW 1      01-01-14    2000
      KW 1      02-01-14    2000
      KW 1      03-01-14    2000
      KW 1      04-01-14    2000
      KW 2      05-01-14    3000
      KW 2      06-01-14    3000
      KW 2      07-01-14    3000
      KW 2      08-01-14    3000
      KW 2      09-01-14    3000
      KW 2      10-01-14    3000
      KW 2      11-01-14    3000
```

And the value is simply devided by 7 (= number of days in a calendar week).

Please, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lubridate` package can help you. It offers functions to easily manipulate dates.

It seems that the year is not variable in your example, so I assume that all the dates are in 2014 (or in the last few days of 2013, since week 1 starts on December 30th). If you are not familiar with `lubridate`, the following will contain many functions that are unknown to you. Use `?` to get help about them (e.g. `?ymd`).

The first step is to get the Monday of the first week of the year. Of course, you could look it up, but `lubridate` can be used to calculate it:

```
library(lubridate)
start_date <- ymd("20140201")
week(start_date) <- 1
wday(start_date) <- "Monday"
start_date
## [1] "2013-12-30 UTC"
```

This first picks an arbitrary day in 2014 and then sets the week to 1 and the weekday to Monday. Now I can get the first day of any calendar week by adding the appropriate number of weeks:

```
start_date + weeks(2)
## [1] "2014-01-13 UTC"
```

Now I create a sample data set with three weeks:

```
data <- data.frame(week  = paste("KW", 1:3), value = c(14000, 21000,  28000))
data
##   week value
## 1 KW 1 14000
## 2 KW 2 21000
## 3 KW 3 28000
```

And the conversion to your desired format works as follows:

```
weeks <- rep(data$week, each = 7)
weeks_num = as.numeric(gsub("KW *", "", weeks))
intervals <- weeks(weeks_num - 1) + days(0:6)
dates <- as.Date(start_date + intervals)
values <- rep(data$value, each = 7)/7
new_data <- data.frame(week = weeks, date = dates, value = values)
new_data
##    week       date value
## 1  KW 1 2013-12-30  2000
## 2  KW 1 2013-12-31  2000
## 3  KW 1 2014-01-01  2000
## 4  KW 1 2014-01-02  2000
## 5  KW 1 2014-01-03  2000
## 6  KW 1 2014-01-04  2000
## 7  KW 1 2014-01-05  2000
## 8  KW 2 2014-01-06  3000
## 9  KW 2 2014-01-07  3000
## 10 KW 2 2014-01-08  3000
## 11 KW 2 2014-01-09  3000
## 12 KW 2 2014-01-10  3000
## 13 KW 2 2014-01-11  3000
## 14 KW 2 2014-01-12  3000
## 15 KW 3 2014-01-13  4000
## 16 KW 3 2014-01-14  4000
## 17 KW 3 2014-01-15  4000
## 18 KW 3 2014-01-16  4000
## 19 KW 3 2014-01-17  4000
## 20 KW 3 2014-01-18  4000
## 21 KW 3 2014-01-19  4000
```

This works as follows:

- First I prepare the dates. Each calendar week is repeated seven times (once for each day). Then the "KW " part is removed and the weeks are converted to numeric. Afterwards, I use the `lubridate` functions `weeks()` and `days()` to construct all the required time intervals since `start_date`.
- The I calculate the values. Each one of them is also repeated for each day of the week and divided by seven.
- Finally, I put the results into a new data frame.

A final remark: This is a complicated solution. If you are certain, that no week will be missing, it is easier to simply produce a series of dates without even considering the column for the calendar weeks as follows:

```
dates <- as.Date(start_date + days(0:(7*nrow(data) - 1)))
identical(new_data$date, dates)
## [1] TRUE
```

So here I simply count the number of weeks with `nrows()`, and produce a sequence of time intervals with `days()` that I then add to `start_date`.
However, if calendar weeks could  be missing, you should  use the more general solution above.

Comment: Thanks a million! Correct, i usually use reshape or timeSeries, but did not use lubricate so far. Data: different years are on different sheets to make things easier. Thanks for both solutions - I might need both indeed. Thank you so much!!

Comment: May I ask something adding up to your answer?

Comment: May I ask something adding up to your answer? I try to use your code for another time series, but cannot generalise it. I.e. I have a data frame with two columsn, df$startdate (E.g. "2015-01-01","2015-03-20","2015-06-05") and df$NrOfDays (e.g. 3,4,6)  I want to add in days intervals <- days(0 : df$NrOfDays) and the create the dates similar like you did dates <- as.Date(start_date + intervals), so the new data starts with "2015-01-01",  "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03, "2015-01-04" (i.e. adding three days). But i don't get it to work ... how would you do this? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I you have a new question, please ask it as a new question. There is nothing wrong with a follow up. If it is useful for those, who want to answer your new question, you can also add a link to this question to your post. Make sure that you add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162): store the example data in a data frame (called, say, `df`) and post the output of `dput(df)`.