# convert year-month string into daily dates

Tags: date

recently I asked how to convert calendar weeks into a list of dates and received a great and most helpful answer: 
[convert calendar weeks into daily dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071009/convert-calendar-weeks-into-daily-dates)

I tried to apply the above method to create a list of dates based on a column with "year - month". Alas i cannot make out how to account for the different number of days in different months.
And I wonder whether the package lubridate 'automatically' takes leap years into account?

Sample data:

```
df <-  data.frame(YearMonth = c("2016 - M02", "2016 - M06"), values = c(28,60))
```

M02 = February, M06 = June (M11 would mean November, etc.)

Desired result:

```
DateList  Values
2016-02-01  1
2016-02-02  1
ect
2016-02-28  1
2016-06-01  2
etc
2016-06-30  2
```

Values would something like

```
df$values / days_in_month()
```

Thanks a million in advance - it is honestly very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the parsing of the line to you.

To find the last day of a month, assuming you have GNU date, you can do this:

```
year=2016 
month=02
last_day=$(date -d "$year-$month-01 + 1 month - 1 day" +%d)
echo $last_day    # => 29 -- oho, a leap year!
```

Then you can use a for loop to print out each day.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Alas, I get error messages when I run                   > last_day=$(date -d "$year-$month-01 + 1 month - 1 day" +%d)
Error: unexpected '$' in "last_day=$". I removed the $ (just to check) but that gave another Error message: : unexpected string constant in "last_day=(date -d "$year-$month-01 + 1 month - 1 day"". What do I miss?

Comment: You missed sharing what language you're using. I see now from the link to your other question that it's R. I gave you a shell answer.

Comment: Ah - sorry! Still interesting - I'll try it in Shell. Thank you so much for sending an answer!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to answer 6 at [Add a month to a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169620/add-a-month-to-a-date) and answer for (how to extract number with leading 0) i got an idea to solve my own question using lubridate. It might not be the most elegant way, but it works.

## sample data

```
data <- data_frame(mon=c("M11","M02"), year=c("2013","2014"), costs=c(200,300))
```

step 1: create column with number of month

```
temp2 <- gregexpr("[0-9]+", data$mon)  
data$monN <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(data$mon, temp2)))
```

step 2: from year and number of month create a column with the start date

```
data$StartDate <- as.Date(paste(as.numeric(data$year), formatC(data$monN, width=2, flag="0") ,"01", sep = "-"))
```

step 3: create a column EndDate as last day of the month based on startdate

```
data$EndDate <- data$StartDate 
day(data$EndDate) <- days_in_month(data$EndDate)
```

step 4: apply answer from [Apply seq.Date using two dataframe columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172263/apply-seq-date-using-two-dataframe-columns) to create daily list for respective month

```
data$id <- c(1:nrow(data))
dataL <- setDT(data)[,list(datelist=seq(StartDate, EndDate, by='1 day'), costs= costs/days_in_month(EndDate)) , by = id]
```